# Advice on way to add information to a MS CRM form for a related entity

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I want do display information for the associated Account record on an invoice form.
The fields are read only and are for information to be shown for the user who is creating or editing the invoice.
From looking at this it seems to be more involved than I though.
1) To display other html on a CRM form I need to use an iframe - I can't just add a text box with an id to then populate using javascript.
2) Then to get the information from the related account record I need to do another lookup, return the field and display it.

To do the query I will do an ODATA call.

Am I on the right track ? Or am I over complicating this and is there a simpler more straighforward method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I know, you're unfortumately not over-complicating.

If you wish to avoid an iframe (which I would), I can suggest a little dirty trick (or hack, if you will)-
Add a text property `new_dummy` to the invoice entity, and add it to the invoice form.
This field will not be read or written by the invoice entity, but will just give you a placeholder to populate with the account data, which you will retrieve with JS.
(yes, this is quite ugly, I know :))

Comment: thank you, I will do that and update this post with my code.
I had considered your hack - adding an extra field - and will probably do that for  other forms - but not first this particular case.